# Cisco command : route policy pass-all

Tags: cisco, routing

I'm having some problem understanding cisco routing policy and  am unable  to find an answer using google. Basically  am I  correct to assume  that the  interface with these  route policies applied will allow  every ipV4 packet in and  nothing out

```
address-family ipv4 unicast
  route-policy pass-all in
  route-policy drop-all out
```

Answer (score 0):

These policies are applied to a bgp instance and act on the route exchange process.  Your router will accept inbound ipv4 bgp routes from neighbors, but not send any routes.  This has no direct effect on data plane (packet) forwarding.

Also the names of the policies don't necessarily correlate to their behavior - we would need to see more of the config to determine exactly what is happening